# how to debug an executable which load .so library at the same time with gdb on linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

Both executable and library are built with -g flags, but when I debug it with gdb it gives me error:
0x8b0cec83 in ?? () from last line of back trace. which I guess it is error from .so library I just built,
the shared library just filled some function pointers inside executable .How to debug both of them same time in gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no additional steps required to debug the library. Chances are that the address you're ending up at (0x8b0cec83) just isn't part of either the application or the library, because you're using an uninitialized (or corrupted) function pointer somewhere.